# getting error using partial view(@Html.Partial("SchemeDetails")) System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MutualFund.Models.SchemeClass]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

In index.cshtml I added the SchemeDetails.cshtml by using a partial view, via

```
@Html.Partial("SchemeDetails")
```

I'm getting this error: `model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List...`

Below are screenshots of these errors:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC5tQ.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9yaT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a List element to the view, but in the SchemeDetails.cshtml, you declared the model as an IEnumerable.

```
@model IEnumerable<MutualFund.Models.SchemeClass>
```

You have to change your InvestClass Index.cshtml like

```
@model IEnumerable<MutualFund.Models.InvestClass>
```